# PHP extract vimeo video "upload.form" field not working

Tags: php, arrays, http-headers, vimeo-api

I am working on a PHP application where I am uploading videos to my Vimeo account from my application browser. How can I get the "upload.form" field HTML mark up to do the upload? Thanks in advance.

```
$prms = [
            "upload" => [
                "approach" => "post",
                "size" => "' . $vsize . '",
                "redirect_url" => "my redirect url am putting it here"
            ],
            "name" => "Question:' . $lessonId . '- ' . $metatitle . '",
            "description" => "' . $questionTitle . '",
            "privacy" => [
                "view" => "disable"
            ],
            "embed" => [
                "volume" => "true",
                "logos" => [
                    "vimeo" => "false",
                    "customs" => [
                        "active" => "false",
                        "sticky" => "false"
                    ]
                ],
                "title" => [
                    "name" => "hide",
                    "owner" => "hide",
                    "portrait" => "hide"
                ],
                "buttons" => [
                    "embed" => "false",
                    "like" => "false",
                    "share" => "false",
                    "watchlater" => "false"
                ],
                "end_screen" => [
                    "type" => "thumbnail"
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $uri = $lib->request('/me/videos', $prms, 'POST');
        $_SESSION['form'] = $uri['body']['upload']['form'];
        header('location:form-fields.php');
        exit();`
```

I have tried to go through the documentation given in Vimeo uploading of videos and github and I cannot get how to get the upload.form field.

Comment: You have an HTML, a PHP application and Vimeo. Is your problem getting the video file from HTML to the PHP application, or from the PHP application to Vimeo?

Comment: check the edited question above chris

Comment: Getting the vimeo upload form to do my upload to vimeo is the issue. where am I missing here: `$uri['body']['upload']['form'];` ?? or Help me get it using my parameters above. from PHP to vimeo i.e

Comment: While debugging this, don't redirect, that'll hide things. After you call `$lib->request()` you'll be give a response which you are storing in `$uri`. Inspect that using `var_dump` or similar.

Comment: Thanks so much I was able to get the response using `var_dump` and size parameter was the issue, it should be an integer so I removed the quotes and also vimeo video name/title should not exceed 128 characters. it worked

Answer (score 0):

My array of parameters required that size be an integer and name not exceed 128 characters. I inspected the response using `var_dump` and I removed the quotes in size parameter and shortened the name to less than 128 characters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).